# Need sql query for matching with three values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
CAccountID  CID   NetworkID
1               1      1
2               1      2
3               2      1
4               2      2
5               2      3
6               3      1
7               3      2
8               3      3
9               4      1
10              4      2
```

I need a query to select all CID having all 3 `NetworkID(1,2,3)` and don't need to display only 1 and 2 `NetworkID`.

Output should be like below,

```
CAccountID  CID  NetworkID
3                2     1
4                2     2
5                2     3
6                3     1
7                3     2
8                3     3
```

Comment: Please mention your sql server version..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `JOIN` :

```
select t.*
from table t inner join
     ( select cid 
       from table
       where NetworkID in (1,2,3)
       group by cid
       having count(distinct NetworkID) = 3
     ) tt 
     on tt.cid  = t.cid;
```

Comment: Hi Sharma,Thank you for your reply. I need CID with having all 1,2,3 NetwordID.. Please check the output i expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from my_table t
where exists(select 1 from my_table
             where CID = t.CID and NetworkID in (1,2,3)
             group by CID
             having count(*) = 3)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I need CID with having all 1,2,3 NetwordID.. Please check the output i expected

Comment: @user2986417 Did try my query? It should return your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from <<tablename>> where cid in(select cid from <<tablename>> group by cid having count(*)=3).
```

Here the subquery will return you all thouse cid which have 3 rows in your table.

Or if you have more network ids then use of **INTERSECT** operator can be helpful:

```
select * from <<tablename>> where cid in (
   select cid from <<tablename>> where NetworkID=1
   INTERSECT 
   select cid from <<tablename>> where NetworkID=2
   INTERSECT
   select cid from <<tablename>> where NetworkID=3
);
```

INTERSECT operator basically returns all the rows common in the queries. Thus, your data unpredicatbility can be handled in this way

Comment: Don't forget that you probably should specify `where NetworkID in (1,2,3)` as data can be unpredictable.

Comment: where NetworkID in (1,2,3) may not help perfeclty. However, I liked your concern about data unpredicatbility, thus, have added another approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Try xml path.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Name B
WHERE (SELECT [text()] = A.Network FROM Table_Name A WHERE A.CID = B.CID 
ORDER BY CID, CAAccount FOR XML PATH('')) = 123
```

CTE Demo:

```
; WITH CTE(CAAccount, CID, Network) AS
(
SELECT 1 , 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 1, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 2, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 2, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 , 2, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 , 3, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 , 3, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 8 , 3, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 9 , 4, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 4, 2
) SELECT *
FROM CTE B
WHERE (SELECT [text()] = A.Network FROM CTE A WHERE A.CID = B.CID ORDER BY CID, CAAccount FOR XML PATH('')) = 123
```

Output:

```
CAAccount   CID Network
3           2   1
4           2   2
5           2   3
6           3   1
7           3   2
8           3   3
```